# Update only the partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm trying to submit the partial view, fire partial view validations and load the main view back (main view will not be the same all the time).Basically, I only want to update the partial view without affecting the main view. Right now when I submit the partial view it loads the partial view action.

Partial View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LeaveReply", "Contactus", new AjaxOptions {  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,    UpdateTargetId = "respond"))
{
                        <h3>Leave a reply</h3>

                            <p class="textarea-block">  
                                <label><span>Message (required)</span></label>                      
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o=>o.Message)
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(o => o.Message, new { @rows="6", @cols="80", @name="message",@class="form-control" })
                            </p>
                            <p class="input-block clearfix">
                               <label class="required"><span>Your Name (required)</span></label> 
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o=>o.Name)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.Name, new { @class="form-control" })
                            </p>
                            <p class="input-block">
                                <label class="required"><span>Email (required)</span></label> 
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o=>o.Email)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.Email, new { @class="form-control" })
                            </p>
                            <p class="input-block last">
                                 <label class="required"><span>Website</span></label> 
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o=>o.WebSite)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.WebSite, new { @class="form-control" })
                            </p>
                            <div class="clear"></div>                            
                            <p class="contact-button clearfix">                    
                                <input type="submit" id="submit-contact" value="Submit">

                            </p>   
                       <div class="clearfix"><br /></div>
                            <div class="kp-success">@ViewBag.Message</div>                     

                        <div id="response"></div>

       }
```

Main View:

```
<div id="respond" class="kopa-border-2">
  @{Html.RenderPartial("_MessagePartial", new Classified.ViewModels.MessageViewModel());}
</div>
```

ContactUs Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult LeaveReply(MessageViewModel model)
  {
       JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

       return PartialView("_MessagePartial", model);
   }
```

Model:

```
public class MessageViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string MessageType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string WebSite { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AddedDateTime { get; set; }
        public int? UserID { get; set; }
    }
```

*Main view is bind to a different model.

Comment: Do you mean its redirecting to a new page displaying only the partial view? If so, you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: hi @StephenMuecke, I added the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and it works. Can you post this as an answer? Thanks